# Keyboard Tabbing thru WPF TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs

I have a wpf tab control.
I need it to behave like this.
Tab thru every control on the page before skipping to the next tab (it now skips to the next tabitem until it reaches the final tab THEN it iterates all the controls on the final tab then switches to the first tab.

So while keyboard tabbing, the ONLY tab that get it's controls iterated by tabbing is the LAST tab.

So I need, a sequence of iterating every control on a tab instead of jumping directly tab to tab (ctrl-tab takes care of that).

Comment: By default, the selected TabItem doesn't change unless you use Ctrl+Tab. How come your TabItems get selected by tabbing? Have you added something else to make it work like that? Care to show some code?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation` Attached Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation(v=vs.110).aspx). From the linked page, this:

> Gets or sets the logical tab navigation behavior for the children of the element that this property is set on.

You can set it to any of the following [`KeyboardNavigationMode` Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode(v=vs.110).aspx) values (from this linked page):

[image]